# Bolt CMS: Customise ckeditor styles

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, bolt-cms

**Question:** I would like add custom styles to the dropdown in ckeditor, e.g. to show a `Button` style adding an `a` tag with class `btn`. Is there a way to do so **within Bolt CMS**?

[image: Style dropdown]
<sub>(source: [jonathanschmid.de](https://www.jonathanschmid.de/ext/stackoverflow-31104705.png))</sub>

**Attempt:** I was hoping to be able to add styles via the `general.wysiwyg.ck` config key, but there doesn't seem to be a suitable option. I managed to achieve what I wanted by editing `bolt-public/view/js/ckeditor/styles.js` – but I guess it's not update-safe.

Does anyone know of a safe way to achieve this within Bolt CMS? If not, I'll try forking to suggest adding `general.wysiwyg.ck.styles` to config.

Comment: I bet there is a css file included...

Comment: Robin, I am not trying to customise the look of ckeditor, but rather add an item to the style dropdown.

Comment: I don't understand it... Could you explain it a bit more? Like wich dropdown,?

Comment: Thanks Robin, I clarified my question and added a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

There's an [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles) about styles.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    { name: 'Button', element: 'a', attributes: { 'class': 'btn' } }
] );
```

and

```
config.stylesSet = 'my_styles';
```

Then if you put the selection into a link, you can apply the style.

However, if you'd like to create a link from scratch, use [`CKEDITOR.editor.insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) within a [custom command](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample-section-creating-an-editor-command) and expose it as a button in the toolbar. Styles combo does not insert new elements.

Comment: Hi oleq, thanks! As mentioned above, I achieved to do so, but need an update-safe solution within Bolt CMS.

Comment: @Jonny You can define the `stylesSet` and set the config anywhere you want but before the editor is initialised. It doesn't have to be `styles.js`.

Comment: But that would mean overriding the admin theme, wouldn't it?